# graceful thread termination with pthread_cond_signal proving problematic

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I need to fire of a bunch of threads and would like to bring them down gracefully.

I'm trying to use `pthread_cond_signal`/`pthread_cond_wait` to achieve this but am running into a problem.

Here's my code. firstly the thread_main

```
static void *thrmain( void * arg )
{
    // acquire references to the cond var, mutex, finished flag and
    // message queue
    .....

    while( true )
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &lock );

        if ( msq.empty() )
        {
            // no messages so wait for one.
            pthread_cond_wait( &cnd, &lock );
        }

        // are we finished.
        if ( finished )
        {
            // finished so unlock the mutex and get out of here
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );
            break;
        }

        if ( !msg.empty() )
        {
            // retrieve msg
            ....

            // finished with lock
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );

            // perform action based on msg
            // outside of lock to avoid deadlock
        }
        else
        {
            // nothing to do so we're
            // finished with the lock.
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, this all looks fine and dandy (to me anyway).

So to tear down the threads I have this method

```
void teardown()
{
    // set the global finished var
    pthread_mutex_lock( &lock );
    finished = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );

    // loop over the threads, signalling them
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < threads.size() ; ++i )
    {
        // send a signal per thread to wake it up
        // and get it to check it's finished flag
        pthread_cond_signal( &cnd );
    }

    // need to loop over the threads and join them.
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < threads.size() ; ++i )
    {
        pthread_join( threads[ i ].tid, NULL );
    }
}
```

Now I know that `pthread_cond_signal` doesn't guarantee which thread it wakes up so I can't signal and join in the same loop. However,  this is where it's all going wrong. `pthread_cond_signal` does nothing if there is no thread waiting so potentially some of the threads won't have been signalled and therefore won't know to exit.

How do I over come this.

M.

***** UPDATE *******
Please don't post that I should use pthread_cond_broadcast as this exhibits EXACTLY THE SAME BEHAVIOUR. it will only wake up a thread which is actually waiting on the cond var. Any thread that is processing during this time and comes back to wait later will have missed the signal and will be oblivious

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you have to change your predicate from

```
if ( msq.empty() ) {
  // no messages so wait for one.
  pthread_cond_wait( &cnd, &lock );
}
```

to

```
while ( msq.empty() ) {
  // no messages so wait for one.
  pthread_cond_wait( &cnd, &lock );
}
```

That's a pthreads thing, you have to guard yourself against [spurious wakeups](http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2005/07/spurious-wakeups.html).

Now you can change that to

```
while ( msq.empty()  && !finished) {
  // no messages so wait for one.
  pthread_cond_wait( &cnd, &lock );
}
```

Since after that check, you already test whether finished is set and exits if so,
all you have to do is signal all the threads.

So, in your teardown function, replace the loop with:

```
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
```

That should ensure all threads wake up, and will see `finished` set to `true` and exit.

This is safe even if your threads are not stuck in `pthread_cond_wait`. If the threads are processing a message, they will not get the wakeup signal, however they will finish that processing, enter the loop again and see that `finished == false` and exit.

Another common pattern for this is to inject a poison message. A poison message is simply a special message your thread could recognise that would mean "STOP", you would place as many of those messages in your queue as you have threads.

Comment: No. This is just a more elegant repeat of the same earlier answer. pthread_cond_broadast will only signal threads which are actually waiting on the cond var.. If any of the threads are busy processing then they WILL NOT WAKE UP when the eventually get to the wait call..

Comment: If they are busy processing, they are already woken up and they will exit on the next loop because of finished being true. since your teardown() holds the mutex when you set finished, you're safe.

Comment: +1 for the poison message approach. I often use that approach and it has proven to be the best solution in many cases.

Comment: It's the signalling all threads that forms the basis of the problem. I can't guarantee that all threads are "waiing" and are in a signallable state. I do like the poison message approach. Presumably you have to set "finished" before sending your poison message.

Comment: I would mark this as the accepted answer were you to change your post so that it doesn't indicate that pthread_cond_broadcast wakes up all the threads..

Comment: As mentioned, the threads don't need to be in a waiting state when you signal them.

Comment: You don't need a finished flag at all if you use a poison message approach.

Comment: You should keep the lock until you finish signalling, my friendly man page says `Unlocking the mutex and suspending on the condition variable is done atomically. Thus, if all threads always acquire the mutex before signaling the condition, this guarantees that the condition cannot be signaled (and thus ignored) between the time a thread locks the mutex and the time it waits on the condition variable.`
see here for reference http://manpage.b0red.de/3thr+pthread_cond_signal

Comment: @Hasturkun "_You should keep the lock until you finish signalling_" Prove it.

Comment: @curiousguy: You mean that I should prove that a race between signalling and waiting can occur? The race itself is fairly well documented and rather obvious. consider the following event order: 1. check condition (false). 2. change condition, signal. 3. wait for signal.  The wake-up will never occur. If 2 was done under the same mutex the race cannot occur.

Comment: @Hasturkun "_You mean that I should prove that a race between signalling and waiting can occur?_" Indeed. "_The race itself is fairly well documented and rather obvious._" It is well documented that there is no possible race.

Comment: @curiousguy: Could you please cite some reference to your claims? I believe I have demonstrated otherwise.

Comment: @Hasturkun Do you really believe that the mutex (mutex stands for MUTual EXclusion) stuff here is cosmetic and unrelated to possible race conditions? Again, please show the "event order" corresponding to the "obvious" race condition (with all the pthread calls that appear in the example obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should be unlocking the mutex after the call to pthread_cond_signal. Also, please check the condition of "finished" before you enter into conditional wait after acquiring the mutex. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You want to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` instead of `pthread_cond_signal()`. The former unblocks *all* threads waiting on a given condition.

Comment: It will still fail if the thread enters the wait after your call.

Comment: Tha's the point.. It only does anything if there's a thread blocking on the cond var. If there isn't then this thread won't know to exit.. This is the crux of the problem,

Comment: @Tronic: the original poster should *still* use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` anyway, rather than the `pthread_cond_signal()` loop. My answer is incomplete (for the problem at hand, one needs to check `finished` before waiting instead of after), but not wrong.

Comment: The code was somewhat tl;dr, but you are probably right. In a more complex case using cond_broadcast gets complicated and cancellation might be better.

Answer (score -2):

I have never used pthreads directly (I prefer Boost.Threads), but I think you should be calling `pthread_cancel` instead of `pthread_cond_signal`.

Comment: No. I specifically do not want to call pthread_cancel which is why I'm trying to implement a nice gracefull shutdown. cancelling a thread is fraught with problems more severe than the one I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You can set pthreads to cancel only at cancellation point, which allows for graceful exit. Thanks for the -1, though :(

Comment: Even cancelling only at cancellation points is dangerous; in many cases it can lead to resource leaks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about that? Sure, a return statement in a function could lead to resource leaks, but considering that care is taken to do proper handling, I don't see why cancellation would be an issue.