# C++ pthread - How to cancel a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a pthread that I created and now I want that in a specific time interval the thread execute some code. But the user should also be able to cancel the thread. How can I cancel a thread and ensure that the thread is not cancelled when it execute the code?

In Java you handle this with

```
while(!isInterrupted)
```

Is there any similar solution with pthreads.

Comment: Why can't you do the same in C++?

Comment: I dont know the specific functions to cancel a pthread or to use a timer with pthreads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Question's example code you are checking some variable.  This is *not* the normal pattern for interrupting threads in Java.

In Java, you interrupt a thread by calling the [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method.

The thread then checks if it is interrupted inside IO and system calls (which can throw `InterruptedException` when this happens; this means a thread that is sleeping or waiting on IO can be awoken when interrupted) or by sampling the [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) flag (typically used in a condition in a loop, as in Question).

The distinction is important; checking some flag variable you've declared is only possible in loops and your own code; the Java interrupting system works for all threads and all non-CPU-blocking code without special effort on the part of the programmer.

**Pthreads** has the [`pthread_cancel()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) pattern which works like the Java interrupting pattern.

Answer (score 4):

[`pthread_cancel`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) is available for sending cancel requests:

> A thread's cancellation type, determined by `pthread_setcanceltype(3)`, may be
>    either asynchronous or deferred (the default for new threads).  Asynchronous
>    cancelability means that the thread can be canceled at any time (usually
>    immediately, but the system does not guarantee this).  Deferred cancelability
>    means that cancellation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function
>    that is a cancellation point.  A list of functions that are or may be
>    cancellation points is provided in `pthreads(7)`.
>
> A thread's cancelability state, determined by `pthread_setcancelstate(3)`, can
>    be enabled (the default for new threads) or disabled.  If a thread has
>    disabled cancellation, then a cancellation request remains queued until the
>    thread enables cancellation.  If a thread has enabled cancellation, then its
>    cancelability type determines when cancellation occurs.

Answer (score 2):

So there are several options:

1: while value checking (works very well, but you don't have much control).

2: check the pthread_cancel manpage, it works to but with strict rules.

3: using pthread_signal, first you need to block, than signal for resume. It has the same issues as the second option.

- Using pthreads cancel and signal will only work from within the thread that must be locked. So setting a variable to initiate the signal block. Unlocking can be done by any other thread.
- The same can be done using mutex or semaphores (pthread_mutex, pthread_semaphore).

A site I recommend: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Answer (score -1):

<strike>There's no specific function to cancel a thread</strike>You can use `pthread_cancel` to cancel the thread, as mentioned (but I would advise against it, unless you know what you're doing), and you have to set up your own timers. But the `while(!isInterrupted)` is pretty acceptable way of doing it.

It should basically be like this:

```
while(!isInterrupted)
{
// whatever you want to do
sleep(howLongYouWantToWait);
}
// clean up and exit the thread function here
```

and in the main thread have a global (or other, see below)

```
volatile bool isInterrupted = false;
```

and set it to `true` when you're done, and `pthread_join` if you want to wait for the thread to finish.

Instead of global, you can use a class variable, or a flag pointer passed to the thread function, or any other way, global is the simplest and the least preferable.

Of course, if you want to cancel the thread while it waits, and not to have it canceled only after it finishes the whole loop, then you need to deal with signals, and other stuff, but I think you're not looking for that.

Comment: Yes, @Maxim, classic example how not to comment on SO. If you don't have anything smart to say - just don't say anything.

Comment: Thanks, now I think I know how to handle it ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317972/graceful-thread-termination-with-pthread-cond-signal-proving-problematic

Comment: @Maxim, irrelevant, and is not what the OP asked for. He showed a specific way he has it implemented and asked for a **similar** solution. I gave him **exactly the same** solution, you can't get more similar than that. You can try to teach everyone to be perfect, but sometimes you've got to listen to what people actually asked you. And needless to mention that it essentially describes the same solution (at least the accepted answer there).